# How can I catch an Excel file's macro error in Powershell?

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I have a scheduled PowerShell script that opens Excel, opens a file and runs a macro.
If an error arises, I need to display it in the shell and interrupt the script. (I can not afford the script to hang while waiting for user input)

Here is my current script ($excelDataPath is defined earlier in the script)

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$Excel.AskToUpdateLinks = $false
$Excel.Visible = $true

$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($excelDataPath)
$Excel.Run("Macro1")
$Workbook.Save()
$Workbook.Close($true)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think from the PowerShell point of view, this will catch and display the exception that has occurred:

```
try {
    $Excel = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
    $Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
    $Excel.AskToUpdateLinks = $false
    $Excel.Visible = $true

    $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($excelDataPath)
    $Excel.Run("Macro1")
    $Workbook.Save()
    $Workbook.Close($true)
    $Excel.Close()
}
catch {
    $exception = $_.Exception
    while ($exception.InnerException) {
        $exception = $exception.InnerException
    }
    # Throw a terminating error. 
    throw $exception
}
finally {
    # IMPORTANT! Always release the comobjects used from memory when done
    if ($Workbook) { [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Workbook) | Out-Null }
    if ($Excel)    { [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel) | Out-Null }
    [System.GC]::Collect()
    [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
}
```

However, as for the VBA macro code you did not show us, you will have to check to see what it does wit any errors via [VBA On Error Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/on-error-statement). Especially the `Err.Raise` and `Throw` statements.

Comment: I sadly don't know what the macro will be as this script will be used on custom files (could be missing file, out of range, any error that could arise in a VBA script)

Comment: @SimonRosenfeld In that case, there is not much more you can do I'm afraid. If you cannot see/edit the actual macro code, all you can do is the above so exceptions will be cought by PowerShell. Hoe exceptions are handled (or not) in the macro code is then anybody's guess.

Comment: Is there any way to at least not have the script hanging? Even with a try catch I'm only able to catch once the popup is clicked

Comment: I don't think so.. What does the (VBA) popup say? You may be able to handle simple errors like 'File not found' yourself before you set Excel to work, like checking in PowerShell if the given `$excelDataPath` really exists using `Test-Path -Path $excelDataPath -PathType Leaf`.