# Catch Excel Messages and send them via eMail

Tags: excel, powershell, email, exception, notifications

starting from this post 
[How can I catch an Excel file's macro error in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53740679/how-can-i-catch-an-excel-files-macro-error-in-powershell)

I would need some help to get PowerShell to send me an email every time a script has run with exceptions on a specific step.

This is the code of my current script.

```
app = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$app.Visible = $False
$app.DisplayAlerts = $False
$wb = $app.Workbooks.Open("\\IESWDBMSFSP001\SHARED02\Technical_Training\PUBLIC\REPORT\USER_FEED\LMS_USERS_QUERY.xlsx")
$wb.Name
$wb.RefreshAll()
$wb.Save()
$wb.Close()
$app.Quit()
```

The critical part is the `$wb.RefreshAll()`, from time to time it fails since the source data are corrupt.

Ideally I would like to trigger a very basic email from PowerShell with ***a fixed subject*** "Error User Query" when an exception is thrown executing just this command `$wb.RefreshAll()`.

I would use a slightly modified version of this code to send the email, so I am fine for this part.
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Send-HTML-Email-Powershell-6653235c

What I do not know and need help with is how to trigger the email, I suppose I will need an if statement: "IF exception, send email, ELSE close and save"

Comment: There's a typo in there: `$Fales` --> `$False`

Comment: I'm not sure which type of error is thrown with `.RefreshAll()`, but could you use a `try/catch` block?

Comment: Error corrected, thank you

Answer (score -1):

The construct you're looking for is called [`try`/`catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally):

```
try {
    $wb.RefreshAll()
    $wb.Save()
} catch {
    $msg = $_.Exception.Message
    Send-MailMessage ... -Body $msg
}

$wb.Close($false)
$app.Quit()
```

This will catch exceptions (terminating errors to be precise) thrown by the `RefreshAll()` (and `Save()`), and will send a mail with the error message.

Comment: $wb.RefreshAll() is a void function.

Comment: @f6a4 Umm... so?

Comment: have you checked it? This throws no error, RefreshAll returns no value.

Comment: @f6a4 No, I haven't. Nor do I need to. Exceptions and return values are 2 different things entirely.

Comment: But I have. Your solution doesn't work, because no error is thrown when the data connection falls.

Comment: Yes folks, when one of the many queries does not find the source file OR when there is a missing column, a popup message is displayed. I will try now.

Comment: Hi, it actually does NOT work, there is an exception, but no excel message pops up on the screen